# Get Location Updates in Background Service - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-geofence, fusedlocationproviderclient

after researching the Android Location FusedLocationProviderClient I am very confused about what you should and should not do!

The use case is: The App holds different locations with latitude and longitude. While the user is walking around the app (with the phone in the pocket, screen off) needs to track if he is close to one of the locations and plays a short beep when closer than a defined range.

Would the Geofence option the best solution? These locations will also change during runtime and periodically - they might also be more than 100. Any suggestion?

I am also thinking about a background service to handle all this when the device moves. This would be more flexible and allows for the reload of the locations as well. Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible combination can be Geofence & GeoFire

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to build a background service to monitor if a user is close to a location. There is already a geofence provided by Google. It uses fusedlocation provider internally.

Please [refer this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

You can combine this with a `FusedLocationProviderClient` and subscribe to location updates. This way you'll get location updates as well.

Comment: geofence do not work properly in background